# Pin code application that increments number of attempts

Tags: c#

I have been trying to finish this small application for counting the number of attempts if you fail to write the correct pin code.

This is my code so far, and I am not understanding why my code isn't working and it keeps on incrementing non stop.

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        int pin_number;
        do
        {
            pin_number = int.Parse(txt_pin.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Hi There");
            if (pin_number != 1326)
            {
                attempts++;
                MessageBox.Show($"pin code is incorrect you have {attempts} of 3 attempts left");
                txt_pin.Text = "";
                txt_pin.Focus();
            }

        } while (pin_number == 1326 && attempts < 3);

    }
```

Comment: *"it keeps on incrementing non stop"* - That isn't the behavior I would expect from this code at all.  I would expect it to never visibly increment and always be the "first attempt".  When you step through this in a debugger, can you clarify specifically what's happening?

Comment: It seems you are expecting that `txt_pin.Focus()` somehow waits until the user entered another PIN for you to parse. This is not the case. It just sets the focus to the edit box and continues. So the loop within your `btn_login_Click` does not make any sense. Suggestion: make the number of attempts a field of your class, instead.

Comment: @David When I type the correct pin it keeps on showing Hi there non stop, but if i type the wrong pin it shows hi there and the number of attempts but it stays as 1 of 3 attempts

Comment: As written, if you enter the correct pin I'd expect it to show 'Hi there' continually. If you enter the wrong pin, I'd expect it to show 'Hi there' once followed by 'pin code is incorrect you have 1 of 3 attempts left'. Is this what happens?

Comment: As a hint for the 'correct' case, `pin_number` will always be `1326` and `attempts` will always be `0`. The while condition will always be `true`. This is the cause of your infinite loop showing 'Hi there'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you click the button is an "attempt", correct?  Well, what's the first thing you do every time you click the button...

```
int attempts = 0;
```

So every attempt is the first attempt.  *Except* when the user gets it right.  Then what you have is an infinite loop because the `pin_number` is correct and `attempts` is never incremented.

First, get rid of the loop entirely.  There's no need to repeatedly check the same input.  Once it's checked, it's checked.  Second, track the number of attempts outside the scope of each attempt, such as at the class level.  Third, check the number of attempts.  Perhaps something like this:

```
private int attempts = 0;
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pin_number;
    pin_number = int.Parse(txt_pin.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Hi There");
    if (attempts < 3 && pin_number != 1326)
    {
        attempts++;
        MessageBox.Show($"pin code is incorrect you have {attempts} of 3 attempts left");
        txt_pin.Text = "";
        txt_pin.Focus();
    }
}
```

Now it's at least checking the pin as expected.  Though at this point you have some logic to reconsider for your program.  Off the top of my head...

1. It never notifies the user if they got the pin right.  Perhaps something else should happen?
2. After the number of attempts is exhausted, there's no warning to indicate this.  It looks exactly as it does if the pin is correct.
3. The text implies that the number of attempts is counting down, but it's actually counting up.

Perhaps something like this might get you started:

```
private int attempts = 3;
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pin_number;
    pin_number = int.Parse(txt_pin.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Hi There");
    if (attempts <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"No more attempts left");
    }
    else if (pin_number != 1326)
    {
        attempts--;
        MessageBox.Show($"Pin code is incorrect you have {attempts} attempts left");
        txt_pin.Text = "";
        txt_pin.Focus();
    }
}
```

Examine each statement in the logic.  For your own logic, particularly around `if` blocks and loops and whatnot, perhaps even grab a piece of paper and draw out the different code paths and write down in each path what should happen there.  Every detail is important, such as when to show a message or when to modify a value.  There's *a lot* of polish that can be added to this code, and I imagine it's an academic exercise so I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have a loop inside your button click handler. You probably don't want that since you want to enable the user to enter a new pin code and click the Login button again.

But that also means that you need to store the number of attempts outside the click handler, since it needs to be saved from one click to the next.

So if you change your code to something like this, I think you'll get the functionality you're after

```
private int attempts = 0;
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pin_number;
    pin_number = int.Parse(txt_pin.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Hi There");
    if (pin_number != 1326)
    {
        attempts++;
        MessageBox.Show($"pin code is incorrect you have {3-attempts} of 3 attempts left");
        txt_pin.Text = "";
        txt_pin.Focus();
    }

    if (attempts >= 3)
    {
        btn_login.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```